# What limits the size of a Python module?

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I am compiling into Python 3(.4.4) and have generated a program that is 250,000 lines long. When I tried running it, Python crashed: Windows (10) reported "python.exe has stopped working". Shorter versions of the "same" output run OK so I'm wondering if the problem is that my program is too long and if so, how I can increase the limit?

Please note that I am not interested in "solutions" where my output is factored into smaller chunks. A monolithic output file is the part of the problem specification.

Here is what the program looks like:

```
import os, sys
from random import randint, seed
from datetime import datetime

DEAD = '_'
ALIVE = '1'

cells = [] # Will be an array of max_row+2 rows each of max_col+2 columns.


# Create initial population of cells
seed( 1.3 )

def repeat_run( max_run ):
    print( '%20s %20s %20s' % ( 'Time', 'Rate', 'Density' ) )
    for run in range( max_run ):
        blank_row = [ DEAD for col in range( 152 ) ]
        for row in range( 152 ):
            cells.append( blank_row.copy() )
        pop = 0
        for row in range( 1, 152-1 ):
            for col in range( 1, 152-1 ):
                if randint( 0, 1 ) == 0:
                    cells[ row ][ col ] = ALIVE
                    pop += 1
        time, rate, density = simulate( cells, pop )
        print( '%20.5f %20.5f %20.5f' % ( time, rate, density ) )
    print()

def num_neighb( row, col ):
    count = 0
    for col_inc in range( -1, 2 ):
        x = col + col_inc
        for row_inc in range( -1, 2 ):
            y = row + row_inc
            if cells[ y ][ x ] == ALIVE:
                count += 1
    return count

def simulate( cells, pop ):
    # Global tally of all cells that ever lived (for calculating average
    # density over the entire run).
    grand_total = pop
    start = datetime.now()

    for gen in range( 10 ):
        pop = 0 # Number of live cells in next generation

        # Initialise next generation of cells
        next_gen = [ [ DEAD for col in range( 152 ) ] for col in range( 152 ) ]

        # Apply birth/death rules
        nn = num_neighb( 1, 1 )
        if cells[ 1 ][ 1 ] == DEAD:
            if nn == 3:
                next_gen[ 1 ][ 1 ] = ALIVE
                pop += 1
        else:
            if nn == 3 or nn == 4:
                next_gen[ 1 ][ 1 ] = ALIVE
                pop += 1

# 250,000 lines later ...

        nn = num_neighb( 150, 150 )
        if cells[ 150 ][ 150 ] == DEAD:
            if nn == 3:
                next_gen[ 150 ][ 150 ] = ALIVE
                pop += 1
        else:
            if nn == 3 or nn == 4:
                next_gen[ 150 ][ 150 ] = ALIVE
                pop += 1


        grand_total += pop

        # Copy next_gen to cells
        for col in range( 152 ):
            for row in range( 152 ):
                cells[ row ][ col ] = next_gen[ row ][ col ]

    end = datetime.now()
    delta = ( end - start ).total_seconds()
    return delta, 231040 / delta, grand_total / 231040

repeat_run( 10 )
```

The full program is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzXE_dVuLZxdT2hUc1NrZUN3NW8).

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: What kind of operations are done within a file? Maybe you're simply hitting memory limit.

Comment: Is that size due to literals in the source file? Start with the latest 3.6 to check for improvements in compiler efficiency. Probably not. I recall someone was looking into it due to Python running out of memory while trying to parse a large dict literal. The problem was heap fragmentation due to poor memory management in the compiler.

Comment: Well 250,000 lines of `1` (which is a legal top-level statement) don't cause any trouble. Then again that's hardly representative of a useful module...

Comment: No problem with a file that consists of 250,000 lines likes `def foo_309739(): return 309739` (different values)...

Answer (score 0):

[Mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2016-July/711988.html) claims:

> So you can have 600KB of source code or 350KB of pyc without any
>   trouble whatsoever.

At the same time, number of locals (and thus function arguments) is capped. Likewise indentation depth is capped too. Limits are 255 and 100 respectively, and you'd get a nice error if you exceed those.